# Adding watermark to image?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to add a watermark to an image. Anyone know how? The watermark image is called "watermark.png"

```
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
let image = UIImage(data: data)!
```

I tried the following code but I need to place the image at position (0,50)

```
  func maskImage(maskImage: UIImage, withMask: UIImage) {
    var maskRef = maskImage.CGImage
    var mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef), CGImageGetHeight(maskRef), CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef), CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef), CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), nil, false)

}
```

Comment: did you not read my question? I used that exact code. BUT I need to place it in a specific position.